# Jquery display a message when toggle is false

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using jquery toggle to show/hide some items and need to display a message when the item is not found. My code below does the toggle hide but I want to show a message when there is nothing to toggle.

```js
const userSearch = ($("#userId").val() || '').toLowerCase();

$('.table tbody tr').find("dl dd").each(function() {
  const userfilter = $(this);
  const userNames = userfilter[0].innerText.toLowerCase();
  const index = userNames.substring(userNames.indexOf(userSearch));
  $(this).toggle(index === userSearch);
});
```

Comment: It seems like you're using a complicated way of writing `userNames.includes(userSearch)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the condition explicitly in an `if` statement, so you can set a variable to indicate whether you found a match.

```js
const userSearch = $("#userId").val().toLowerCase();

let foundMatch = false;
$('.table tbody tr').find("dl dd").each(function() {
  if (this.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(userSearch)) {
    $(this).show();
    foundMatch = true;
  } else {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});

if (!foundMatch) {
  // display message
}
```

There's no need for `|| ''` when setting `userSearch`. `.val()` always returns a string (unless the selector doesn't match anything, which shouldn't happen).

Comment: This second answer works for me except I have to click on the alert box twice to dismiss it.  if (!foundMatch) {
                            alert("No Match for the Search Name!!");
                           
                        }

Comment: I can't think of any reason why that would be, unless you're running the code twice.

Comment: Put `console.log("starting search")` in the code to see if it's being run multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to just check the length of the items and if it is not greater than zero, show a message.

Try this

```
const userSearch = ($("#userId").val() || '').toLowerCase();
if(!($('.table tbody tr').find("dl dd").length > 0)) {
  alert('no dd elements');
} else {
  $('.table tbody tr').find("dl dd").each(function() {
    const userfilter = $(this);
    const userNames = userfilter[0].innerText.toLowerCase();
    const index = userNames.substring(userNames.indexOf(userSearch));
    $(this).toggle(index === userSearch);
  });
}
```

Comment: But `$(this).length` will **always** be greater than zero, because `this` is the current `<dd>` element in the iteration.

Comment: My bad I just fixed it.

Comment: This was my first interpretation of the question, but I think they want to alert when searching for `userSearch` doesn't find anything, not when there are no rows to search.

Comment: This answer works for me except I have to click on the alert box twice to dismiss it. if (!foundMatch) {
  // display message
}